# How to change exchange server name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

How do I change the Exchange server name in Outlook 2003? It is greyed out and underlined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't edit the name while you have Outlook open, you have to go through the control panel.

1. Close Outlook
2. Go to **Control Panel --> Mail**
3. Click **Email Accounts** button
4. Now you should be able to go through the standard steps of add/change email account and it shouldn't be grayed out anymore

Comment: i have the same problem but everytime i change the server when i start outlook it sets the old server again